# New features generated from SymbolicTransformer do not match the rule?

Tags: python, feature-extraction, feature-selection, gplearn

I have same features.I put them into SymbolicTransformer, fit.
This is the result of fit :

[sqrt(X145),
 log(div(add(div(div(X270, X568), sub(X177, X147)), neg(sqrt(X3))), sqrt(div(log(X240), sub(X32, X481))))),
blablabla...]

The column of X145:

[image]

After transform, the column of new feature generated from sqrt(X145)（the first column of new features） is:

[image]

I suppose the column sqrt(X145) is:

[sqrt(0), sqrt(5), sqrt(2), sqrt(10), sqrt(15)]

Obviously, I have some misunderstanding with SymbolicTransformer about generating features. 
Please correct me if I am wrong.